# Call to undefined function iconv_strpos() laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I'm trying to get a site up and running on a VPS server running cpanel.

I've uploaded the site and configured to point at the public folder which appears to be working (or pointing to the right folder)

However I'm getting a 500 server error. In an error_log I'm getting this error:

`[18-Aug-2016 21:44:09 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv_strpos() in /home/spadsdrama/public_html/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php on line 351`

SO it looks like PHP is missing this function?

PHP version is 5.6
Laravel 5.2

Pulling out my hair to get this sorted

I had this site working correctly on a Plesk server but switched to a Cpanel one (might be regretting this now!)

What am I missing - what configuration is missing?

Thanks

Comment: Iconv extension is enabled by default in PHP, unless you specifically disable it at compilation. Laravel is actually using a "partial, native PHP implementation for the Mbstring extension." https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-mbstring. Try to force it to use the native function instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php PHP extension for this function support. You can do this from ISP-manager of VPS, if it exists, or with SSH console server.

Comment: Yep that was the trick - I reconfigured the php package from within cpanel and all working now - thank you

Comment: @Ray I have the same problem, how to do for fix the error?